# Вызов всплывающего меню при старте

Tags: android

Есть приложение, можем ли мы вызывать всплывающее меню при старте? Без нажатий на кнопки итп.
Просто показывать всплывающее меню с выбором некоторых вариантов.

Comment: Поставил минус - негоже с таким ником задавать такие банальные вопросы. Читайте гайды.

Comment: Поставил плюс - нормальный ник, чё.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вполне можем. При старте приложения:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    b.setMessage("Привет!");

    AlertDialog a = b.create();

    // TODO ...
}
```

Comment: Ну внешний вид будет другой хотелось бы чтото подобное на контекстное меню

Answer (score 0):

Можете. один из возможных вариантов: в Application создаете флаг в onCreate. По флагу во входном Activity в onResume() дергаете onCreateContextMenu() или то меню, которое вам нужно, после этого флаг сбрасываете.

Comment: а 3 параметра?

Comment: 3 параметра - созданое вами контекстное меню, если я правильно понял что вам надо

Comment: view то нет

Comment: входного активити ваше view